# "aria-expanded" attribute don't support any content editor

Tags: html, tinymce

"aria-expanded="true"  don't support any content editor

like:  `<a aria-expanded="true">`

please help me how to support aria-expanded="true" in tag in Editor

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code will help you. Check it out!

```css
a[aria-expanded="true"]{
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<li class="active">
   <a href="#3a" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true"> 
       <span class="network-name">Google</span>
   </a>
</li>
<li class="active">
   <a href="#3a" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false"> 
       <span class="network-name">Google</span>
   </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set whatever attribute you'd like on a TinyMCE container element. What exactly do you mean when you say "Doesn't support"?